# Is there any formal research into the concept of "nothing more permanent than a temporary government program"?

Tags: political-theory, statistics

According to a quote [attributed to Milton Friedman](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/did-milton-friedman-say-that-nothing-was-so-permanent-as-a-temporary-government), "there's nothing more permanent than a temporary government program". Is there any formal academic research into this concept, i.e. comparing the duration of "temporary" programs to "permanent" programs or analyzing the number of times a certain rule was extended to prevent it from lapsing?

Comment: Not my DV, but given the extent of China's [measures](https://www.garda.com/crisis24/news-alerts/465526/china-authorities-maintaining-covid-19-related-international-travel-restrictions-and-domestic-controls-as-of-april-11-update-35) that make travelling there a pain, it probably doesn't make much difference. Apparently the US is easing some restrictions on Chinese students though https://www.nbcnews.com/news/asian-america/us-eases-covid-19-restrictions-chinese-students-rcna783

Comment: @Fizz I mean, its hard to travel to Taiwan too but Taiwanese travelers are not banned. At this point the Chinese ban is purely about government inertia.

Comment: Well, the US considers Taiwan a much more friendly country, so they are less likely to take drastic action(s) against it. Think of Trump's [delayed](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/16/politics/us-travel-bans-late-new-york-city-coronavirus/index.html) ban on EU travel... which he was also much more inclined to lift early https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-usa-travel-exclusi-idUSKBN29N20Y

Comment: I don't think this is answerable on this site. It's like asking "is there any formal research about how [Murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) apply to government programs?" — sure it applies, but it is not about politics. VTC/OT.

Comment: @bytebuster [its similar to this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/is-there-a-ranking-of-states-based-on-how-unitary-federalized-they-are), which was allowed

Comment: The government set up a board to study this very question; it's still investigating after many years...

Comment: Hmm, it's an intriguing question, but hard to answer, because "government program" isn't very clearly defined. Are you talking about policy in general, or about institutions...? (At the most general level, even West Germany's constitution isn't called constitution but 'basic law', because it was meant to be temporary until reunification. And that was some 30 years ago.)

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica anything which was officially intended to be "temporary" but then ended up lasting for a long time

Comment: Temporary restrictions is not what the quote was about -- it's about programs. I'd say remove the second paragraph from your question. "[The many New Deal programs still in existence seem to fit into this category.](https://www.mercatus.org/publications/government-spending/do-intergovernmental-grants-create-ratchets-state-and-local-taxes)" Also, "[Note 1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11127-012-9957-5)" mentions variations of the quote related to Federal grants.

Comment: @RickSmith sure, done

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but implicitly most theories of institutional change deal with this question and tend to emphasize the incremental nature of change and the fact that most change is adaptive rather than dramatic. I guess this would also apply to institutions that were meant to be provisional (Thelen, Streeck, Hall). Then there is the literature on agenda dynamics, which at first seems to state the opposite: Policy agendas change suddenly. But also here, the point is that there are long periods of agenda stability, which are only occasionally "punctuated" (Baumgartner/Jones).

Comment: I'll point out that MF was a dyed-in-the-wool economist, so if he'd meant this as an analytical claim — not as fiscal conservative cant, as seems more likely — he'd have researched it himself. But as a rule 'programs' are (as best I understand it) *never* designed to be temporary. temporary measures are handed off to established institutions; programs imply the creation of new institutional structures (allocation of money and materials and establishment of new bureaucratic structures), and no one bothers to do that unless they intend that particular service to persist.

Comment: it's an antigovernmental play on the common saying "nothing more permanent than a temporary solution that works". If something works to solve a common problem, why stop the fix?

Comment: @dandavis because taxes are a drain on society

Comment: @JonathanReez Taxes are what keeps society running. There are many things that would break down if we depended on private business/individuals to take care of because there is no direct benefit/profit for a lot of those things for the person providing the service.

Comment: @JoeW yes but tax magnitude is important. I.e. Switzerland has the lowest income taxes in Europe (except for micro nations) and they’re doing just as well as the highest tax countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez That isn't what you said though. You made a generalized statement about taxes in general not a comment about keeping them at reasonable levels.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's a myth; nations with higher taxes tend to have higher GDP PPP, per Heritage Foundation.

Comment: @dandavis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates - sort by Income tax and see where Switzerland is at. Its possible to have low taxes if you minimize wasteful spending, which is most spending done by the government.

Comment: @JonathanReez "Most"? So if waste were curtailed and the federal budget went to 49% of last year, we wouldn't be negatively impacted? I have a hard time buying that, got sources?

Comment: @dandavis depends on which part would be cut, of course. If the government focuses on eliminating as many government jobs as possible and curtailing useless contractors, it could be great. If they instead keep up the wasteful parts and stop maintaining roads, it could be bad.

Comment: @JonathanReez veering off-topic, but Switzerland can afford low corporate income taxes because they are small and therefore net beneficiaries of global tax competition. They have little tax base to lose and much tax base to gain. Basically, they are a tax haven and their beggar-thy-neighbour "business model" cannot simply be emulated by others (and certainly not by every state at once). Switzerland's spending isn't terribly austere, on the other hand. It's somewhat austere, but that's mostly down to direct democracy, which means many veto points over spending decisions.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica yes and that veto is exactly what other countries lack so that spending goes towards building infrastructure rather than handouts to organization of dubious practical use to taxpayers

Comment: @henning I was wrong about Switzerland and I apologize. See [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64098/how-is-switzerland-able-to-maintain-low-tax-levels). They're just sneaky about hiding some of their taxes as "technically not a tax" contributions.

Comment: @JonathanReez no need. Yes, they are at the top of their game. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any formal research into the concept of “nothing more permanent than a temporary government program”?
> Is there any formal academic research into this concept, i.e. comparing the duration of "temporary" programs to "permanent" programs or analyzing the number of times a certain rule was extended to prevent it from lapsing?

**TL;DR**

The information to answer the question is scant and dated. I finally stopped trying to find a comprehensive source.

There is a question as to the context of Friedman's quote. Specifically, whether that quote refers to all programs or only those programs "started through grant funding," as indicated in the conclusion to the first summarized article, below. The article addresses temporary grant funding. The article claims that federal grant money results in on-going expenses to the state or local government, thus giving the temporary grant permanency.

In the second article, from a government commission in 1961, it is noted that "once a Federal grant begins, it never ends." While this is refuted, somewhat, it does show there were concerns about such grants after they began in earnest under Franklin Roosevelt. This article addresses reasons why temporary grants become permanent, as well.

---

In the working paper for "Do Intergovernmental Grants Create Ratchets In State And Local Taxes?", August 2010, the authors, in a section titled with Friedman's quote, note that

> While one can find quotes from several notable individuals, such as this paper's opening quote by Milton Friedman, that *state* the observation that temporary programs tend to become permanent, it is worthwhile to briefly address the reasons why this may occur from the academic literature. [Page 4](https://www.mercatus.org/system/files/Do-Intergovernmental-Grants-Create-Ratchets.WP_.Corrected.10.4.10.pdf#page=5)

They reference other papers to address those reasons. Later, they note

> Because it is impossible to break out data on federal grants into which funding is temporary versus permanent, we simply note that our data uses all federal grants and that therefore we need to interpret the results with this in mind. [Page 6](https://www.mercatus.org/system/files/Do-Intergovernmental-Grants-Create-Ratchets.WP_.Corrected.10.4.10.pdf#page=7)

In the conclusion, they claim

> Our results clearly demonstrate that grant funding to state and local governments results in higher own source revenue and taxes in the future to support the programs initiated with the federal grant monies. Our results are consistent with Friedman's quote regarding the permanence of temporary government programs started through grant funding, as well as South Carolina Governor Mark Sanford's reasoning for trying to deny some federal stimulus monies for his state due to the future tax implications. [Page 24](https://www.mercatus.org/system/files/Do-Intergovernmental-Grants-Create-Ratchets.WP_.Corrected.10.4.10.pdf#page=25)

Also, the [U.S. Advisory Commission on Intergovernmental Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Advisory_Commission_on_Intergovernmental_Relations), which existed from 1959 through 1996, did limited research in 1961. "Table 4," as mentioned below, identifies 14 grants that were terminated.

[Periodic Congressional Reassessment of Federal Grants-In-Aid to State and Local Governments](https://library.unt.edu/gpo/acir/Reports/policy/A-8.pdf#page=27), June 1961

> **III. The Problem of Terminating or Redirecting Grants-In-Aid**
>
> On frequent occasions it is alleged that "once a Federal grant begins, it never ends." From a factual standpoint this allegation is almost but not quite correct. "Never" should be amended to "hardly ever." Table 4 lists those grants-in-aid from the National Government to the States which have been terminated.
>
> This list is not impressive. With the exception of "general relief," none of the grants listed were in support of any continuing function of State or local government. On the other hand, there have been many efforts in the Congress aver the years to terminate or redirect particular grant programs. During the 1950's, at one time or another, recommendations were made either by the President or by special committees established to study particular programs, to cease, taper off, or otherwise modify a dozen or more major grant programs, including those for vocational education, resident instruction at land-grant colleges, school lunches, and school construction and operation in federally affected areas. In none of these instances did the Congress decide to discontinue the program in question.
>
> [...]
>
> The Commission notes two general obstacles to terminating or redirecting the grants, once they have served their purpose. In the first place, with the initiation of a new grant, vested interests--both governmental and private--in its continuation come into being. Subject matter staffs are created or expanded at National, State and local levels of government for the purpose of administering the grant program. Aside from any instincts of organizational self-preservation which may exist, these staffs, if they are competent and conscientious, acquire a sense of mission with respect to their particular program. Being responsible for a specific program or function they are not especially concerned with general problems of intergovernmental fiscal relations across-the-board, Consequently, their recommendations for change in the grant program are typically in the direction of expansion rather than contraction.
>
> Furthermore, once a particular grant continues for a few years it becomes an integral part of State and local budgets and constitutes one of the assumed sources of revenue in the process of budgetary planning. With States and localities being always hard-pressed with respect to revenue sources, State and local officials naturally are averse to seeing a particular grant reduced or eliminated with the consequent necessity of diverting State or local funds to continue the function at the existing level. Also, those parts of the private sector of the economy which benefit from the grant program, such as professional organizations, suppliers of material, or the providers of services which are purchased with grant funds, are all interested in continuing the program. Attempts to reduce the amount of Federal contribution are resisted strongly, presumably on the premise that it is easier to defend an existing Federal appropriation than to obtain increased amounts from State or local funds.
>
> Secondly, efforts to redirect grant programs toward newer and more urgent problems within a given program area usually result in an additive rather than a substitutive appropriation. This is illustrated by the history of Federal grants for vocational education. Some of the subject matter areas which the original act was designed to stimulate in the national interest have long ceased to have any commanding priority in terms of national manpower shortages. On the other hand, the vocational training of practical nurses and of electronic, chemical and other technicians has been federally stimulated, not by substituting the new for the old, but through retaining the old and adding the new.

Comment: [Another interesting paper](https://www.everycrsreport.com/files/20140415_R40638_cf1519b63c9a3dbfe158870ac3f37a2fd242c25d.pdf)

Comment: @JonathanReez - There is [a more recent paper](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R40638.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The terms you're looking for are "[Bureaucracy Lifecycle](https://www.jstor.org/stable/976746?seq=1)" and the cluster of related terms including [Mission Creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_creep)

There are a number of scholars who have examined the ways in which government programs, as they outlive their original intentions, face an existential threat and since they are populated by people who crave employment, meaning, and prestige, act to expand their mission(s) so as to continue existing and garnering resources.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two search results for "duration of temporary government programs":

[Timely, Targeted, and Temporary? An Analysis of Government Expansions over the Past Century](https://www.mercatus.org/system/files/Taylor-Timely-Targeted-Temporary.pdf) - Taylor & Castillo 2015, George Mason University, Mercatus Center [*note, an ideologically libertarian institution*]

> This paper examines episodes of major government expansion during
> economic emergencies along with the contraction, or lack thereof, once the
> emergency has passed. We analyze broad measures such as federal government
> spending, both in absolute terms and as a percentage of GDP. We conclude that
> most countercyclical spending programs do not follow the three Ts, which may
> undermine their ultimate effectiveness and explain why many economists are
> skeptical of such policies

---

[Nothing So Permanent As Temporary Measures](https://www.innovations.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/donohue_00_civillib.pdf) -- Donohue 2000, Harvard University, Belfer Center for Science and Int'l Affairs

Focusing closely on analysis and categorization of causes for the long duration of 20th century UK "emergency" policy in Northern Ireland,

> This paper examines these questions and proposes that a confluence of primary factors and secondary circumstances – many of which are common to liberal, democratic states – perpetuated the emergency measures beyond their intended life.